# Open a modal from a button in another component Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 components. One called TestSearchTool and another one called TestModal. I'd like to show my Modal when I click a button in the TestSearchTool component. These 2 components are siblings in the hierarchy so I didn't really find a way to pass the value between them ( there is vuex but I'd like to find a way without it )
I'm using Bootstrap 5 and Vue 3 to do this since Bootstrap Vue doesn't work on Vue 3.

Here is my TestModal component :

```
<template>
<div>
  <div class="modal fade" ref="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="modal.hide()" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="modal.hide()">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    modal: null
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.modal = new Modal(this.$refs.exampleModal)
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is my TestSearchTool component :

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="container ml-5 mt-3 border-1 rounded pl-5 pt-5 pr-5">
          <div class="row mb-4">
             <div class="col-md-6 mb-4" >
          <label for="test" class="label-form">Titre</label>
          <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Rechercher par le titre du test" v-model="testName" type="text"  id="test" class="form-control">
          </div>
             <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
            <label for="candidat" class="label-form">Candidat</label>
          <select  v-model="CandidateName" class="form-select" id="candidat">
            <option  value="" selected>Tous les candidats</option>
          </select>
          </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                 <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                   <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 d-inline-block">
                     <!-- Modal is shown on this button's click !-->
                    <button  type="button" @click="this.$emit('clickDone')" class=" btn btn-primary col-12 col-sm-11 mb-sm-0 mb-sm-0 mb-4 float-sm-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-circle-plus"></i> Ajouter Un Test</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 d-inline-block">
                      <button  @click="deleteTests" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary col-sm-12 col-12" v-if="false"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-circle-minus"></i>  Supprimer Le(s) Test(s)</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              <button id="searchTest" @click="searchBy" class="col-12 btn btn-primary" ><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Rechercher</button>
             </div>
             
          </div>
            
          </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
components:{
},
data(){
    return {
        testName:'',
        CandidateName:'',
        show:false,
    }
},
methods:{
},
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

And here is the parent component (called Tests) :

```
<template>
  <div>
  
     <test-search-tool></test-search-tool>
     
  <test-modal></test-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestSearchTool from "../components/TestSearchTool.vue"
import TestModal from "../components/TestModal.vue"
export default {
components : {
    DashboardNavbar,
    TestSearchTool,
    TestModal,
},
mounted(){
      document.body.style.backgroundImage='url("")';
      document.body.style.background="white";
      
}
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know the goal of writing codes in **components** in simple words is to have special duties specific to that component. So when we define a "modal" component, we expect that it shows modal content for us. So in my opinion it is not correct to say modal component (here called `TestModal.vue`) and `TestSearchTool.vue` are siblings. You could use `TestModal.vue` every where in your app structure that you need a modal content to be shown. In other words the `TestModal.vue` component does not have any special content or logic to be the direct child of `Tests.vue` (the parent component).

With the above description I used `TestModal.vue` as child of `TestSearchTool.vue` and by using `props` and `watch` and `emit` capabilities of Vue, here is the codes of **all** 3 components:

> `TestSearchTool.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container ml-5 mt-3 border-1 rounded pl-5 pt-5 pr-5">
      <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4" >
          <label for="test" class="label-form">Titre</label>
          <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Rechercher par le titre du test" v-model="testName" type="text"  id="test" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
          <label for="candidat" class="label-form">Candidat</label>
          <select  v-model="CandidateName" class="form-select" id="candidat">
            <option  value="" selected>Tous les candidats</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
          <div class="col-12 mb-4">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 d-inline-block">
              <!-- Modal is shown on this button's click !-->
              <button  type="button" @click="this.$emit('clickDone')" class=" btn btn-primary col-12 col-sm-11 mb-sm-0 mb-sm-0 mb-4 float-sm-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-circle-plus"></i> Ajouter Un Test</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 d-inline-block">
              <button  @click="deleteTests" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary col-sm-12 col-12" v-if="false"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-circle-minus"></i>  Supprimer Le(s) Test(s)</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- *********************** -->
          <!-- this button is responsible for showing modal. you can use such a button in other parts of your app if you define "data" correctly -->
          <button id="searchTest" @click="dataModal = true" class="col-12 btn btn-primary" ><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Rechercher</button>
        </div>

        <test-modal @closeModal="dataModal = false" :showModal="dataModal"></test-modal>
        <!-- *********************** -->
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestModal from "../components/TestModal.vue"
export default {
  name: "TestSearchTool",
  components:{
    TestModal
  },
  data(){
    return {
      testName:'',
      CandidateName:'',
      show:false,
      /* this data is used for showing modal */
      dataModal: false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

> `TestModal.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" ref="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="hideModal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="hideModal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'
export default {
  name: "TestModal",
  data: () => ({
    modalInstance: null
  }),
  props: {
    showModal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    showModal(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      if (newValue === true) {
        this.modalActive();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    modalActive: function () {
      this.modalInstance = new Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {
        target: "#my-modal",
        backdrop: "static"
      });
      this.modalInstance.show()
    },
    hideModal: function () {
      console.log("closed");
      this.modalInstance.hide();
      this.$emit('closeModal');
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> `Tests.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <test-search-tool></test-search-tool>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestSearchTool from "../components/TestSearchTool.vue"

export default {
  name: "Tests",
  components : {
    TestSearchTool
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```